# How to get the day that I have more orders created

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a rails application and I want to know in my class `Order` the day that I have more creations.

Could you help me please :D
I'm using as database the postgresql

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post your `Order` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max_orders_in_a_day = Order.all.group_by{ |x| x.created_at.all_day }.sort_by { |a,b| b.length }.last

max_orders_in_a_day[0] #=> The day
max_orders_in_a_day[1] #=> An array with the related Order objects
```

Comment: Better:
Replace 
`Order.all.group_by{ |x| x.created_at.all_day }.sort_by { |a,b| b.length }.last`
with
`Order.all.group_by{ |x| x.created_at.all_day }.max_by { |a,b| b.length }`